# c# TaskFactory ContinueWhenAll unexpectedly running before all tasks complete

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, task

I have a data processing program in C# (.NET 4.6.2; WinForms for the UI). I'm experiencing a strange situation where computer speed seems to be causing Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll to run earlier than expected or some Tasks are reporting complete before actually running. As you can see below, I have a queue of up to 390 tasks, with no more than 4 in queue at once. When all tasks are complete, the status label is updated to say complete. The ScoreManager involves retrieving information from a database, performing several client-side calculations, and saving to an Excel file.

When running the program from my laptop, everything functions as expected; when running from a substantially more powerful workstation, I experience this issue. Unfortunately, due to organizational limitations, I likely cannot get Visual Studio on the workstation to debug directly. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this for me to investigate?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int startingIndex = cbStarting.SelectedIndex;
    int endingIndex = cbEnding.SelectedIndex;
    lblStatus.Text = "Running";
    if (endingIndex < startingIndex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ending must be further down the list than starting.");
        return;
    }
    List<string> lItems = new List<string>();
    for (int i = startingIndex; i <= endingIndex; i++)
    {
        lItems.Add(cbStarting.Items[i].ToString());
    }

    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(cbMonth.SelectedItem.ToString());

    ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(4, 4);
    List<Task<ScoreResult>> tasks = new List<Task<ScoreResult>>();
    for (int i = startingIndex; i <= endingIndex; i++)
    {
        ScoreManager sm = new ScoreManager(cbStarting.Items[i].ToString(),
            cbMonth.SelectedItem.ToString());
        Task<ScoreResult> task = Task.Factory.StartNew<ScoreResult>((manager) =>
            ((ScoreManager)manager).Execute(), sm);
        sm = null;
        Action<Task<ScoreResult>> itemcomplete = ((_task) =>
        {
            if (_task.Result.errors.Count > 0)
            {
                txtLog.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    txtLog.AppendText("Item " + _task.Result.itemdetail +
                        " had errors/warnings:" + Environment.NewLine);
                });

                foreach (ErrorMessage error in _task.Result.errors)
                {
                    txtLog.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        txtLog.AppendText("\t" + error.ErrorText +
                            Environment.NewLine);
                    });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                txtLog.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    txtLog.AppendText("Item " + _task.Result.itemdetail +
                     " succeeded." + Environment.NewLine);
                });

            }
        });
        task.ContinueWith(itemcomplete);
        tasks.Add(task);
    }
    Action<Task[]> allComplete = ((_tasks) =>
    {
        lblStatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Complete";
        });
    });
    Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll<ScoreResult>(tasks.ToArray(), allComplete);
}
```

Comment: What exactly are seeing that is causing you to think this?

Comment: The program stops processing (confirmed via task manager usage going to 0, no further log entries, and no further output files created) and updates the status as complete after processing ~1/3 of the entries. It does always seem to be the same entry that is the last one processed before processing inexplicably stops and it shows "complete"

Comment: Of course, I just said that and, in a new attempt I made to at least get some info by adding some task status information to the log, it has successfully gone past the item it has stopped at before.

Comment: It seems to have stopped shortly after on a different item; with this, I was able to see that a number of tasks have shown up as "faulted"

Comment: Can you add [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Why are you using tasks for this? Unless the computation of `ScoreManager.Execute()` is very intensive then there doesn't seem to be any good reason to use tasks.

Comment: It is very intensive.

Comment: @ww2406 - Can you please post the `ScoreManager` class?

Comment: @Enigmativity see my follow up question. I didn’t know when I first posted this that tasks don’t propagate errors to the main thread. The real problem is some sort of mysterious connection leak that I haven’t been able to figure out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61820220/connection-leak-c-ado-net-even-though-sqlconnection-created-with-using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discovering state was IsFaulted, I added some code to add some exception information to the log (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library). Seems the problem is an underlying database issue where there are not enough connections left in the connection pool (Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.)--the additional speed allows queries to fire more quickly/frequently. Not sure entirely why, as I do have the SqlConnection enclosed in a using clause, but investigating a few things on that front. At any rate, the problem is clearly a little different than what I thought above, so marking this quasi-answered.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating fire-and-forget tasks, that you don't wait or observe, here:

```
task.ContinueWith(itemcomplete);
tasks.Add(task);
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll<ScoreResult>(tasks.ToArray(), allComplete);
```

The [`ContinueWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith) method returns a `Task`. You probably need to attach the `allComplete` continuation to these tasks, instead of their antecedents:

```
List<Task> continuations = new List<Task>();
Task continuation = task.ContinueWith(itemcomplete);
continuations.Add(continuation);
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll<ScoreResult>(continuations.ToArray(), allComplete);
```

As a side note, you could make your code half in size and significantly more readable if you used [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) instead of the old-school `ContinueWith` and `Invoke((MethodInvoker)` technique.

---

**Also:** setting an upper limit to the number of `ThreadPool` threads in order to control the degree of parallelism is extremely inadvisable:

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(4, 4); // Don't do this!
```

You can use the [`Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel) class instead. It allows controlling the [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) quite easily.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'm not familiar enough right now with async/await to actually get something workable in the way I need it to in the time frame I need it in--I spend some time (unsuccessfully) trying earlier and settled on this as it worked. Honestly my .NET background is really more 2.0 days, so even the whole idea of tasks is a little different than what I'm used to :D Will investigate assigning ContinueWith to a Task instead of using the antecedent. (Also, +1 for the response, but b/c my rep is too low, it won't show I guess)

Comment: @ww2406 yeap, I wouldn't suggest either to jump on the async-await wagon without knowing anything about its mechanics, because despite its apparent simplicity it can be quite tricky. But definitely it is a hugely important technology to know nowadays.